# Change default size of background image

Tags: html, css

Into my css file I have:

```
input.myInput {
background-image:url ('search.png');
background-size:120px 120px;
}
```

Also html file is:

```
<input type='text' class='myInput' >
```

How I can change the background image size?

Comment: Are you not aware of pixel size units?? To change to 140 pixels change to `background-size:140px 140px` and change the 1st `background-size` to `background-image` - it's incorrect

Comment: The first css attribute should be background-image

Comment: What do you mean by "How I can change the background image size?" you want the image to change size with window size or do you want to make the image bigger ? if you want to make the image bigger just change the `background-size:120px 120px;` values to what you want.

Comment: Yes i change it but the problem exists.

Comment: So what is the problem that exists?

Comment: For my project i want to make the background image smaller.

Comment: Your question is not clear what do you really want to do and what is your issue we really can't understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: @user8190974 see my answer. Make it smaller by changing the pixel size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first attribute sets the image URL, so it should be `background-image`, not `background-size`.

```
input.myInput {
    background-image:url('search.png');
    background-size:120px 120px;
}
```

To increase the image size, change the `background-size` pixel units to other dimentions. For example, `background-size:60px 60px;`.

To keep your to 100% of its container, set it to

`background-size: 100%;`

or

`background-size: contain;`

Answer (score 0):

This works 100%.
Check the [Codepen](https://codepen.io/abinthaha/pen/RZLRMQ) link here.

CSS

```
.myInput {
  background-image: url('http://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/search-icon-png-21.png');
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right center;
}
```